# If $L_1L_2$ is regular language, is $L_2L_1$ regular as well?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

> If $L_1L_2$ is regular language, is $L_2L_1$ regular as well?

I think the answer is no, but I'm not sure how to contradict.

Comment: Perhaps there's a simple example where $L1$ is a subset of the words of the form $a^n$ and $L2$ is a subset of words of the form $a^nb$. This way the sequences of $a$s get merged in the first case but are separated in the second.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L_1 = \{a^ib^j | i \ge j \ge 0\}$ and $L_2 = \{b^k c | k \ge 0\}$.

Now $L_1L_2$ is $\{a^i b^{j+k} c | i \ge j, j \ge 0, k \ge 0\}$, in which there is no relationship between $i$ and $j+k$, so that's equivalent to $\{a^ib^jc | i, j \ge 0\}$, which is the regular language $a^*b^*c$.

But $L_2L_1$ is $\{b^k c a^ib^j | i \ge j \ge 0, k \ge 0\}$ which is not regular (as can easily be seen by intersecting it with $ca^*b^*$).

(Example inspired by a comment from [@TomKern](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/908546/tomkern).)

Answer (score 2):

Also following [@TomKern](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/908546/tomkern) suggestion, here is a simpler example on a two-letter alphabet.

Let $L_1 = a^*$ and $L_2 = \{a^{n^2}b \mid n \geqslant 0\}$. Then $L_1L_2 = a^*b$ is regular, but $L_2L_1= \{a^{n^2}ba^m \mid n,m \geqslant 0\}$ is not regular since its intersection with the regular language $a^*b$ is equal to $L_2$, which is not regular.